# How to create a link in a apex-pl/sql-region?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

for a Application in Apex i want to create some links with the htp-class with the properties:

1. The link must refers to a internal page of the app.
2. If the Link is clicked, i want to set the value of a "hidden-item" in the refered page

Some ideas?

greetings

Answer (score 1):

Please, read the following documentation chapter: [Understanding URL Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35125/concept_url.htm#BEIFCDGF). It will answer on both of your questions.

> some links with the htp-class

I don't know what is htp-class. May be, you mean `HTP` package or HTML `class` attribute.

Just want to note that you can use built-in capabilities of such APEX components like Reports and Lists to generate links to the pages of your app including item values setting. Here are the links to the docs: [Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35125/nav_list.htm), [Column Link in IR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35125/bldapp_rpt_int.htm#BABEAFDA), [Column Link in Classic Report](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35125/bldapp_rpt_att.htm#BCECBBGH).

Good luck,
Alex

Comment: thanks! the url-syntax helps a lot. Lists look nice, i want to take a look